# wpf determine dialog show type?

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog, window, non-modal

I have a window in a WPF project that is used in a couple different places.  Depending on the use I would like to be able to show it modal (ShowDialog()) or non modal (Show()).  When a particular button is clicked on the UI it should fire an event if it's non-modal but return a dialog result if it's modal.

My question; is there a way to determine within the window code how it's been shown?  I know you get an exception if you try to set dialog result if it's non modal but I'd rather not try and catch an exception.

I can set a simple boolean property that I can set manually telling me which it is.  Not difficult so I can do that if that's the only way, but it would be nice to not have to remember to set that value each time.

Comment: This has been answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368926/how-do-i-determine-if-a-wpf-window-is-modal

Comment: Sorry, I searched but didn't find that one for some reason, thanks!